# IntelliJ 15 Works Slow and eats 1GB of RAM

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I just have installed `intelliJ IDEA 15` but it's somehow laggy and uses a lot of RAM. Sometimes more than 1GB on my 4GB-RAM laptop.
Are previous versions of `intelliJ` better in performance?
How can i make it faster?
And another problem I have is with Auto completion and correction. 
Where are these two settings? Cause it doesn't seem as good as Eclipse.

Comment: It all depends on your project size,  but first-index by Intellij is slow. Also, if you anticipate a huge project size in near future and other softwares like Apache webserver/Tomcat, DB like Oracle/Postgres, etc, then you should update your hardware.

Comment: The uncomfortable truth is IntelliJ is very over engineered. It is good but that comes at a price, and low powered machines do not appear to have been a consideration and there are quite a few gotchas and bugs. Android Studio a variant of IntelliJ is even worse.  That said measure for measure it is better then Eclipse slightly. However, consider what you want to do with it. If it is just learning to code or the basics of object oriented development ask yourself if Eclipse is enough for your needs and maybe stick with that.

Comment: I just saw mine was using 5GB of RAM...  

Comment: you are lucky with 1GB... mine is at 4.25GB at the moment

Comment: This is a result of caching everything to RAM to make all of its insight and analysis tools run faster. Upgrading my machine to 16GB of RAM (for around $50) made it run significantly faster.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Usually if you have performance problems, the first place I would advice is to look at the plugins which are activated, perhaps you don't need those plugins.

`File -> Settings -> Plugins`
[image: Filter to show only enabled plugins]

Secondly, intelliJ indexes your files so that all its wonderful searches and short cuts, so, if you have a huge project, the first indexing will take some time.

For tips on auto-completion etc. Take a look at the official docs.
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/auto-completing-code.html

**Extra Tips**
When I started using IntelliJ, I found lot of videos on youtube about how to use it, these tips *have* helped me get more productive. I don't want to start a debate on Eclipse vs IntelliJ vs Netbeans etc., but each IDE has a vision and a way it was intended to be used, so moving from one to another *does* need a ramp up time.