# IntelliJ Build 181.5281.24 consumes more than 1GB of RAM

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, ram

I am using IntelliJ build 181.5281.24 for Java development and it consumes more than 1GB of memory (of my 4-GB RAM computer). It constantly freezes and becomes quite difficult to use at times.

I tried out a solution given here [IntelliJ 15 Works Slow and eats 1GB of RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266252/intellij-15-works-slow-and-eats-1gb-of-ram) but I am not sure of the plugins to uninstall or disable owing to the fact that some of them could be necessary for the normal running of the IDE? Another solution altogether would be much appreciated.

Comment: Installing more RAM/upgrading would be the best solution.

Comment: You can disable the plugins based on the technologies you are using for java development. This links http://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea shows all the plugin available ( I have not used intelli-j so not sure about the default plugins intelli-j have) but you can search a bit about the installed plugins and can take the decision if you can uninstall them or not.

Comment: I appreciate the surprising accept 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

- Yes, IntelliJ requires a lot of memory. It is a powerful tool, and I just checked ... 850 MB, 5 seconds after launch and still increasing. Which is no surprise, as I have really large projects.
- I am running the free edition, without any specific plugins installed.

Leading to real answer: a development machine in 2018 needs to be equipped with way more than 4 GB of memory.

Seriously: the answer here is *not* to spend many hours to fine tune IntelliJ to work for you (with halfway acceptable performance). Instead, your option space boils down to:

- Adding memory to your machine, or to buy a new one with at least 8 to 16 GB
- Not using a fully fledged IDE such as IntelliJ (maybe BlueJ could do, or editors such as Atom)

Comment: A good alternative solution. However, I believe that an attempt towards fine tuning IntelliJ would be better especially for those who might not be in such a position to increase their RAM for one reason or another - notwithstanding your perception of a development machine of 2018.

Comment: @shadrqengisa I wouldn't call that my perception. Things are what they are. 4 GB is nothing in 2018. I understand that you might not have access to better hardware, but rest assured: nobody being serious about Java development would consider 4 GB sufficient or appropriate. Maybe for a small hobby project, but then: you don't need IntelliJ either. You are basically investing your time to enhance your shovel with extra paint, and a hardened paddle ... assuming that digging a swimming pool will work out then. I am telling you that you should use an excavator for that task, not a shovel.

Comment: And then: sure, when you *believe* that you can hand pick the plugins you do (not) need, and that dramatically cuts down IntelliJ memory consumption: fine, go for that. But expect that you have to constantly come back and check such things. Believe me: when you start *fighting* a tool, you are wasting your time. If the tool can't easily be adjusted to your needs, then you need to change plans.

Comment: It's okay @GhostCat. I get your argument.